# JIRA 6.0 Username Change on Database

Tags: jira

I'm working on making a bulk change to our usernames inside of JIRA. I'm using JIRA 6.0 and I have changed individual names one by one. I looked at which tables JIRA changed, when I made the individual username change. The username was changed at app_user, cwd_user, and cwd_membership. I went through and changed the usernames inside those three tables. I then re-indexed JIRA and I don't see the changes. Any ideas on what step I'm missing?

Comment: There are at least a dozen columns in a handful of tables where you also have to change them.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but the answer might help someone else.

JIRA 6.2 + supports renaming of users. Upgrade and rename.